# Rails 4: composed_of mapping to JSON store attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, virtual-attribute

I have the following models set up

```
# task.rb
class Task << AR
  # everything all task objects have in common
end

# login_request.rb
class Tasks::LoginRequest < Task
  store :data, accessors: [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :expires_at]

  composed_of :valid_until, class_name: 'DateTime', mapping: %w(expires_at to_s), constructor: Proc.new { |date| (date && date.to_datetime) || DateTime.now }, converter: Proc.new { |value| value.to_s.to_datetime }
end
```

I'm using the `datetime_select` helper in my form:

```
# _form.html.haml
= f.datetime_select :valid_until
```

This works quite well, but when I call `update` in my controller with the submitted form data I get the following error message:

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [2014, 4, 2, 9, 48] to valid_until (can't write unknown attribute 'expires_at')]
```

So, I'm guessing the updated method tries to manipulate the `attributes` hash directly, but obviously it can't find the attribute `expires_at`, since it's a simple accessor method of the JSON column `data`.

I know I could simply add this field to the DB and it would probably work - although there's no need then to have a `composed_of` statement. But I'd rather not go this route, because not every task has a `expires_at` column.

How can I overcome this error? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently compose_of is not supporting this scenario since it writes directly to attributes that are assumed to be in the database. I wrote a tweaked compose_of version that does (based of Rails 4.0.2 version)

Putting this in initialize folder:

```
#/initialize/support_store_in_composed_of.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module Aggregations
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def clear_aggregation_cache #:nodoc:
      @aggregation_cache.clear if persisted?
    end

    module ClassMethods

      def composed_of_with_store_support(part_id, options = {})
        options.assert_valid_keys(:class_name, :mapping, :allow_nil, :constructor, :converter, :store)

        name        = part_id.id2name
        class_name  = options[:class_name]  || name.camelize
        mapping     = options[:mapping]     || [ name, name ]
        mapping     = [ mapping ] unless mapping.first.is_a?(Array)
        allow_nil   = options[:allow_nil]   || false
        constructor = options[:constructor] || :new
        converter   = options[:converter]

        reader_method(name, class_name, mapping, allow_nil, constructor, options[:store])
        writer_method(name, class_name, mapping, allow_nil, converter, options[:store])

        create_reflection(:composed_of, part_id, nil, options, self)
      end

      private
        def reader_method(name, class_name, mapping, allow_nil, constructor, store=nil)
          define_method(name) do
            if @aggregation_cache[name].nil? && (!allow_nil || mapping.any? {|pair| !read_attribute(pair.first).nil? })
              if store.present?
                attrs = mapping.collect {|pair| send(pair.first)}
              else
                attrs = mapping.collect {|pair| read_attribute(pair.first)}
              end

              object = constructor.respond_to?(:call) ?
              constructor.call(*attrs) :
              class_name.constantize.send(constructor, *attrs)

              @aggregation_cache[name] = object
            end
            @aggregation_cache[name]
          end
        end

        def writer_method(name, class_name, mapping, allow_nil, converter, store=nil)

          define_method("#{name}=") do |part|
            klass = class_name.constantize
            unless part.is_a?(klass) || converter.nil? || part.nil?
              part = converter.respond_to?(:call) ? converter.call(part) : klass.send(converter, part)
            end
            if part.nil? && allow_nil
              mapping.each { |pair| self[pair.first] = nil }
              @aggregation_cache[name] = nil
            else
              if store.present?      
                mapping.each { |pair| send("#{pair.first}=", part.send(pair.last)) } 
              else
                mapping.each { |pair| self[pair.first] = part.send(pair.last) }
              end
              @aggregation_cache[name] = part.freeze

            end
          end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

And using it like this would solve your problem.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  store :data, accessors: [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :expires_at]


  composed_of_with_store_support :valid_until,  class_name: 'DateTime', mapping: %w(expires_at to_s),
   constructor: Proc.new { |date| (date && date.to_datetime) || DateTime.now },
    converter: Proc.new { |value| value.to_s.to_datetime },
    store: true

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had `valid_until` as a store accessor directly, but then I can't use the `datetime_select` helper on it with the magic still working cause I get the mentioned multi parameter error. And I know that I can create a manual wrapper, but I wanted to avoid programming it myself since all the functionality is basically there - but it's not working as expected.

Comment: I see. It does not work like that right now so I wrote version that does.